# Curve modifier won`t allow for input of object?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

When I try to pick my bezier curve as the object for my curve modifier it will give a *modifier is disabled*  message when I press apply.

The curve in edit mode

[[image: the curve in edit mode][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tsI4.png)

[image]

Comment: is it really a curve? try converting it to a mesh and then back to a curve with Alt+C in object mode.

Comment: the object you are pointing to is probably not a bezier curve. Can you show it edit mode to verify that ?

Comment: @lemon I added an image with the curve in edit mode

Comment: that's definitively a mesh and not a curve.

Comment: I used alt+c as you advised to convert it into a mesh

Comment: you have to convert it to a curve, Alt+C and select `Curve from Mesh/Text`

Comment: OK, the imagine you added confirms that this object is not a curve, but a mesh (so the answer given below is correct)

Comment: @homersimpson please consider a different way of capturing gifs so that we don't have to endure advertising form the app used. Please read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/1056#1056

Answer (score 6):

It's named "curve" because it was originally a curve, but somehow it got converted to a mesh.

You need to use "Object -> Convert To... -> Curve from Mesh" to make it back into an actual Bezier curve again. Then you'll be able to use it in the modifier.